# Is there a theory for forcing "sludge" through a network, analogous to electric current flows?

Tags: flows, network-theory

I'm familiar with the correspondence between reversible Markov chains, random walks, and electric current flows, as described in [Probability on Trees and Networks](https://rdlyons.pages.iu.edu/prbtree/) by Lyons and Peres.

Is there an analogous theory for forcing "sludge" through a network? Can one model "back pressure"? Can one tune the network or flow to obtain good isoperimetric inequalities? Will the frontier behave differently than thresholding a random walk?

I'm looking for pointers to the literature. "Sludge" is clearly the wrong search term. Analogous to how drag force evolves between laminar flow and turbulent flow, a parametrized generalization that subsumes both "sludge" and electricity would be appealing.

Comment: Are you familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slurry_pipeline ?